# How to average each element within list of lists with variable data lengths?

Tags: r

I am attempting to create an average list of multiple lists which

1. may not all contain the same variables and
2. contain variables of different lengths and sizes.

For any given variable name, the size and dimensions of that variable will be the same in all lists.

I am currently using a nested for loop that creates a dataframe of each variable with each individual list forming a column, then average with rowMeans() across columns. This works but it is *really* slow. Each of the individual lists is from a different trial of data and has over 1200 variables and is about 1.5 MB.

Below is a sample of the general idea for three lists. There are variables one element long, 5 elements long, and a 3x3 matrix. In this simple example the third list (L3) is missing the variables C1 and C5. The idea would be to create a new list meanL = mean(L). Desired output is reproduced with the meanL variable.

Currently to handle the matrix variables I pivot longer, average across columns of trials, pivot wider. Since there are few of them I would be happy to have a solution for just the vector variables if that is simpler. It seems like this is possible with `aggregate()` if I first limit lists to variables of the same length? I have not attempted this yet.

```
# Reprex of list data
L1 <- list(
  A1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(1)), 
  B1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(2)), 
  C1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(3)),
  A5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(1:5)), 
  B5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(6:10)), 
  C5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(11:15)),
  M1 = data.frame(X1 = as.double(1:3), 
                  X2 = as.double(4:6),
                  X3 = as.double(7:9))
  )

L2 <- list(
  A1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(4)), 
  B1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(5)), 
  C1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(6)),
  A5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(5:1)), 
  B5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(10:6)), 
  C5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(15:11)),
  M1 = data.frame(X1 = as.double(9:7), 
                  X2 = as.double(6:4),
                  X3 = as.double(3:1))
)

L3 <- list(
  A1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(7)), 
  B1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(8)), 
  A5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(11:15)), 
  B5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(16:20))
)

L <- list(L1, L2, L3)
L

# To reproduce desired output ...
L1M1 <- pivot_longer(L1$M1, cols = X1:X3)
L2M1 <- pivot_longer(L2$M1, cols = X1:X3)
M1 <- data.frame(T1 = L1M1$value, T2 = L2M1$value)

meanL <- list(A1 = tibble(X1 = mean(c(L1$A1$X1, L2$A1$X1, L3$A1$X1))), 
              B1 = tibble(X1 = mean(c(L1$B1$X1, L2$B1$X1, L3$B1$X1))), 
              C1 = tibble(X1 = mean(c(L1$C1$X1, L2$C1$X1))),
              A5 = tibble(X1 = rowMeans(cbind(L1$A5$X1, L2$A5$X1, L3$A5$X1))), 
              B5 = tibble(X1 = rowMeans(cbind(L1$B5$X1, L2$B5$X1, L3$B5$X1))),
              C5 = tibble(X1 = rowMeans(cbind(L1$C5$X1, L2$C5$X1))),
              M1 = rowMeans(M1)
              )

meanL$M1 <- data.frame(X1 = meanL$M1[1:3],
                       X2 = meanL$M1[4:6],
                       X3 = meanL$M1[7:9])
```

Below is an image showing some of the first few variables of the first list and the associated data types. Data are either 1 row x 1 column long, 51 rows by 1 column long, or 51 rows by 3 or 6 columns long.

[image]

Note that this question has been update with new reprex data, previous solutions worked for previous data.

Comment: So what's the desired output for this sample input so we can verify that possible solutions work as intended? What exactly does your current code look like?

Comment: Added example for desired output as requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're ok with converting tables to matrices, a simple recursive function combined with `relist`:

```
library(data.table)

tomat <- function(x) {
  if (length(dim(x)) > 1) {
    if (!is.array(x)) x <- as.matrix(x)
  } else if (is.list(x)) {
    x <- lapply(x, tomat)
  }
  
  x
}

L <- tomat(list(L1, L2, L3))
LL <- unlist(L, 0)
LL <- LL[!duplicated(names(LL))]

relist(
  colMeans(
    m <- rbindlist( # save for additional calculations
      lapply(c(list(LL), L), \(x) as.data.table(t(unlist(x)))),
      fill = TRUE
    )[-1],
    na.rm = TRUE
  ),
  LL
)
#> $A1
#>      X1
#> [1,]  4
#> 
#> $B1
#>      X1
#> [1,]  5
#> 
#> $C1
#>       X1
#> [1,] 4.5
#> 
#> $A5
#>            X1
#> [1,] 5.666667
#> [2,] 6.000000
#> [3,] 6.333333
#> [4,] 6.666667
#> [5,] 7.000000
#> 
#> $B5
#>            X1
#> [1,] 10.66667
#> [2,] 11.00000
#> [3,] 11.33333
#> [4,] 11.66667
#> [5,] 12.00000
#> 
#> $C5
#>      X1
#> [1,] 13
#> [2,] 13
#> [3,] 13
#> [4,] 13
#> [5,] 13
#> 
#> $M1
#>      X1 X2 X3
#> [1,]  5  5  5
#> [2,]  5  5  5
#> [3,]  5  5  5
```

We can use `m` to get, e.g., standard deviation:

```
relist(Rfast::colVars(as.matrix(m), TRUE, TRUE), LL)
#> $A1
#>      X1
#> [1,]  3
#> 
#> $B1
#>      X1
#> [1,]  3
#> 
#> $C1
#>           X1
#> [1,] 2.12132
#> 
#> $A5
#>            X1
#> [1,] 5.033223
#> [2,] 5.291503
#> [3,] 5.773503
#> [4,] 6.429101
#> [5,] 7.211103
#> 
#> $B5
#>            X1
#> [1,] 5.033223
#> [2,] 5.291503
#> [3,] 5.773503
#> [4,] 6.429101
#> [5,] 7.211103
#> 
#> $C5
#>            X1
#> [1,] 2.828427
#> [2,] 1.414214
#> [3,] 0.000000
#> [4,] 1.414214
#> [5,] 2.828427
#> 
#> $M1
#>            X1       X2       X3
#> [1,] 5.656854 1.414214 2.828427
#> [2,] 4.242641 0.000000 4.242641
#> [3,] 2.828427 1.414214 5.656854
```

If there are characters lurking in there:

```
L1 <- list(
  A1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(1)), 
  B1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(2)), 
  C1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(3)),
  A5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(1:5)), 
  B5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(6:10)), 
  C5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(11:15)),
  M1 = data.frame(X1 = as.double(1:3), 
                  X2 = as.double(4:6),
                  X3 = as.double(7:9)),
  T1 = tibble(x1 = "C")
)

L2 <- list(
  A1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(4)), 
  B1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(5)), 
  C1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(6)),
  A5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(5:1)), 
  B5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(10:6)), 
  C5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(15:11)),
  M1 = data.frame(X1 = as.double(9:7), 
                  X2 = as.double(6:4),
                  X3 = as.double(3:1)),
  T1 = tibble(x1 = "B")
)

L3 <- list(
  A1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(7)), 
  B1 = tibble(X1 = as.double(8)), 
  A5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(11:15)), 
  B5 = tibble(X1 = as.double(16:20)),
  T1 = tibble(x1 = "A")
)

L <- tomat(list(L1, L2, L3))
LL <- unlist(L, 0)
LL <- LL[!duplicated(names(LL))]

relist(
  type.convert(
    rbindlist(
      lapply(
        c(list(LL), L),
        \(x) as.data.table(t(unlist(x)))
      ),
      fill = TRUE
    ), "NA", 1
  )[-1, lapply(.SD, \(x) if(is.numeric(x)) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE) else x[1])], # or `else x[0]` (for NULL) or `else x[.N + 1L]` (for NA)
  LL
)
#> $A1
#>      X1
#> [1,] 4 
#> 
#> $B1
#>      X1
#> [1,] 5 
#> 
#> $C1
#>      X1 
#> [1,] 4.5
#> 
#> $A5
#>      X1      
#> [1,] 5.666667
#> [2,] 6       
#> [3,] 6.333333
#> [4,] 6.666667
#> [5,] 7       
#> 
#> $B5
#>      X1      
#> [1,] 10.66667
#> [2,] 11      
#> [3,] 11.33333
#> [4,] 11.66667
#> [5,] 12      
#> 
#> $C5
#>      X1
#> [1,] 13
#> [2,] 13
#> [3,] 13
#> [4,] 13
#> [5,] 13
#> 
#> $M1
#>      X1 X2 X3
#> [1,] 5  5  5 
#> [2,] 5  5  5 
#> [3,] 5  5  5 
#> 
#> $T1
#> $T1[[1]]
#>     
#> 1: C
```

Comment: Thanks. With my real data I receive: "Error in colMeans(rbindlist(lapply(c(list(LL), L), function(x) as.data.table(t(unlist(x)))),  : 
  'x' must be numeric" Perhaps my reprex data wasn't exactly accurate. All elements within the main lists are stored as Type list with Value of tibble. Would that make a difference?  I will attach an image to the original question that may help.

Comment: A bit more info, it is colMeans() that is causing the error. rbindlist() is working.

Comment: It would help if you could `dput` an example set of lists that throws the error. Are all the elements inside the lists numeric? I get the same error if I change any of the elements to character.

Comment: See the update on a few ways to handle characters.

Comment: I updated the reprex data in the code in the question above to better reflect the actual format. With this current data I receive the error: Error in setnames(x, value) : 
  Can't assign 1 names to a 5 column data.table

Comment: Works! And so much faster. Returned averages are not in tibbles but I can deal with that. As the number of lists (number of trials) varies, is there a simple way to deal with this line for N lists L? L <- tomat(list(L1, L2, L3))

Comment: `L <- mget(ls(pattern = "L[0-9]"))`

Comment: Thanks, that was a misleading question, sorry. I don't actually ever have separate lists L1, L2, L3, etc. These are read from files directly into the list of lists L. So I could make this line work using  L <- tomat(list(L[[1]], L[[2]], L[[3]])), but how to generalize for L[[N]]?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255252/discussion-between-bmacwilliams-and-jblood94).

Comment: Not sure I understand. If `L` is already your list of lists, then just subset it, e.g., `L2 <- L[1:N]`, then use `L2` instead of `L` if you want to average the elements inside`L2`.

Comment: Thanks. One further question, I also compute standard deviations. Should this be done with exactly the same method duplicated, so just start with relist() can just change the mean function and get a retuned list of just SD values, or is there a way to do this inside the relist () function so that returned list contains both Ave and SD elements?

Comment: Probably easiest to call it again.

Comment: I take that back. See the updated answer.

Comment: This is amazingly fast. Is there a similar method to compute the number of values N used for mean/sd of each variable? I am currently using the previous method with sum(!is.na()). Works fine but not nearly as fast as recycling m. I poked around Rfast but nothing obvious. colCount() seems to just report frequency of specified values.

Comment: `colSums(!is.na(m))`?

Comment: Yup, should have came up with that myself, but thanks again for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach first unnesting the list to a wide data.frame with `rrapply()` (in package `rrapply`) and second calculating the means across (list) columns with `Reduce()`:

```
library(rrapply)

rrapply(L, how = "bind") |>
  lapply(FUN = \(x) Reduce(`+`, x[!is.na(x)]) / sum(!is.na(x)))

#> $A1
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $B1
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $C1
#> [1] 4.5
#> 
#> $A5
#> [1] 5.666667 6.000000 6.333333 6.666667 7.000000
#> 
#> $B5
#> [1] 10.66667 11.00000 11.33333 11.66667 12.00000
#> 
#> $C5
#> [1] 13 13 13 13 13
#> 
#> $M1
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    5    5    5
#> [2,]    5    5    5
#> [3,]    5    5    5
```

**Edit:** since the question changed, here is an updated answer. The output is a flat list of columns, but can be made into a list of data.frames again if necessary by nesting by parent names.

```
rrapply(L, how = "bind", options = list(coldepth = 2)) |>
  lapply(FUN = \(x) Reduce(`+`, x[!is.na(x)]) / sum(!is.na(x))) 

#> $A1.X1
#> [1] 4
#> 
#> $B1.X1
#> [1] 5
#> 
#> $C1.X1
#> [1] 4.5
#> 
#> $A5.X1
#> [1] 5.666667 6.000000 6.333333 6.666667 7.000000
#> 
#> $B5.X1
#> [1] 10.66667 11.00000 11.33333 11.66667 12.00000
#> 
#> $C5.X1
#> [1] 13 13 13 13 13
#> 
#> $M1.X1
#> [1] 5 5 5
#> 
#> $M1.X2
#> [1] 5 5 5
#> 
#> $M1.X3
#> [1] 5 5 5
```